# Need to write in C a logical statement calculator that takes two inputs (either a number or a letter) and a (<, >, =) operator and checks if true

Tags: c, logic, calculator

The calculator should take inputs like (23>3) or (a>9) and prints if it's true or false. My main difficulty is doing it for letters. I only managed to do it for numbers. I don't know how to define the `scanf` to accept a letter. When a letter is compared to a number, I need to compare the letters' ASCII values. So, if I do `a>9` it actually checks if `97>9` (97 is the ASCII value of 'a').

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    char operator;
    printf("Please write your logical statement:");
    scanf("%d %c %d", &num1, &operator, &num2);
    if (operator=='>')
    {
        if (num1>num2)
        {
            printf("True");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("false");
        }
    }
    else if (operator =='<')
    {
        if (num1<num2)
        {
            printf("True");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("false");
        }
    }
    else if (operator == '=')
    {
        if (num1==num2)
        {
            printf("True");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("False");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify it to also accept characters?

Comment: It has to be a letter.

Comment: If the user enters `0`, do you want to compare with the ASCII code of the digit `0` (which is `48`) or do you want to compare with the value `0`? Or is the user not allowed to enter `0`? Is the user only allowed to enter values between `a` to `z`, and `A` to `Z`?

Comment: If the user enters 0 then it's just the normal number '0'. Only if it's a letter compared to a number does it check the letters ASCII value and compares it to 0. so a>0 checks if 97>0

Comment: Right. Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Is the user allowed to enter spaces in the input, such as `23 > 3`?

Comment: No. No spaces. Just statements like 1>a or 5<b

Comment: Really appreciate all your help.

Comment: "Only if it's a letter" That's a strange requirement. How are letters special? Furthermore, what if the user enters two letters, like `100 > ab`? What if the user enters `1a < 2c`? What happens if the user enters `>><`?

Comment: They only enter one letter. I have been advised to use maybe getchar() instead of scanf()? Does that help?

Comment: @YotamKatz: I think it is best to always read an entire line of input at once, using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). See my answer for further information.

Comment: "They only enter one letter" It looks like you have extremely disciplined and/or highly paid users. The rest of us make mistakes, don't read manuals, and/or are downright mischievous.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. A fairly straightforward way is to read your two operands as *strings* and then have a function that either converts those strings into their component numbers or returns the (ASCII) value of the (single) character.

Here is such a function and a modified version of your `main` to use it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // For strlen
#include <ctype.h>  // For isalpha

int GetValue(char* input, int* value)
{
    if (sscanf(input, "%d", value) == 1) { // Successfully read a number
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strlen(input) == 1 && isalpha(input[0])) { // For single letters ...
        *value = input[0];
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // Return zero to indicate failure
}

int main(void)
{
    char in1[10], in2[10]; // Buffers for input operands (may like to make bigger)
    char op;
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Please write your logical statement:");
    // See notes below for an explanation of the format specifiers...
    if (scanf("%9[a-zA-Z0-9] %c %9[a-zA-Z0-9]", in1, &op, in2) != 3) {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!GetValue(in1, &num1)) {
        printf("Invalid operand 1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!GetValue(in2, &num2)) {
        printf("Invalid operand 2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (op == '>') {
        printf((num1 > num2) ? "True" : "False");
    }
    else if (op =='<') {
        printf((num1 < num2) ? "True" : "False");
    }
    else if (op == '=') {
        printf((num1 == num2) ? "True" : "False");
    }
    else {
        printf("unrecognized operator");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A short explanation of the `%9s[a-zA-Z0-9]` format specifier (the "set" format described on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)): This allows any characters from the three ranges ('a' thru 'z', 'A' thru 'Z' and '0' thru '9') as input to the corresponding `char[]` arguments. Thus, the input (to the first field) will stop when one of your operators is seen. The '9' immediately after the '%' limits input to the two fields to 9 characters, thus preventing buffer overflow; if you change the size of your `in1` and `in2` arrays, then change that value accordingly (it should be no greater than *one less* than the size of the array, to allow for the `nul`-terminator).

Note that I have also added some (possible) improvements:

1. Always check the value returned by `scanf`, to make sure it succeeded
2. You can use the "conditional (ternary) operator" to make your output code (`printf` blocks) rather more succinct.

Comment: If you want upper and lower case letters to be 'merged', then you can use `*value = tolower(input[0]);` in the `GetValue` function.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to use

```
scanf( "%c %c %c", &digit1, &operator, &digit2 );
```

but this would only work if the user enters single digits, not a multi-digit number such as `23`.

Instead of using the function `scanf`, it is generally recommended to always read an entire line of input at once, including the newline character. The function `scanf` can do nasty things, such as leaving the newline character on the input stream, [which can cause trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/12149471).

In order to read a whole line of input at once, I recommend using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

I recommend that you treat all characters up to, but not including the operator character, as a separate string. You can then determine whether this string is a valid integer by using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). If it is not, you can then check the length of the string, to verify that it is only a single character. If it represents neither, then your program should print an error message and exit.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//This function will convert a string to a number. If the
//string represents an actual number, it will return this
//number. If the string contains a single letter, it will
//return the ASCII code of this letter. Otherwise, the
//function will exit the program with an error message.
long convert_string_to_number( const char *str )
{
    long num;
    char *p;

    //attempt to convert the string into a number
    num = strtol( str, &p, 10 );

    if ( p == str )
    {
        //failed to convert string to number, so we must
        //now determine whether it is a single letter
        if ( strlen(str) == 1 && isalpha( (unsigned char)str[0] ) )
        {
            //return the ASCII code of the character
            return str[0];
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Error: Operand must be either a number or a single letter!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //verify that all remaining characters are whitespace
    //characters, so that input such as "6abc<23" gets
    //rejected
    for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            printf( "Error: Unexpected character found!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    return num;
}

bool perform_operation( long num1, char operator, long num2 )
{
    switch ( operator )
    {
        case '<':
            return num1 < num2;
        case '>':
            return num1 > num2;
        case '=':
            return num1 == num2;
        default:
            printf( "Error: Invalid operator!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    char line[200];
    char *p;
    char operator;
    long num1, num2;

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to find operator
    p = strpbrk( line, "<>=" );

    //print error message and abort if no operator found
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error: No valid operator found!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remember the operator
    operator = *p;

    //overwrite the operator with a null character, to
    //separate the input string into two strings
    *p = '\0';

    //make the pointer p point to the start of the second
    //string
    p++;

    //attempt to convert both strings to a number
    num1 = convert_string_to_number( line );
    num2 = convert_string_to_number( p );

    //perform the actual operation and print the result
    if ( perform_operation( num1, operator, num2 ) )
    {
        printf( "True" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "False" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
abc
Error: No valid operator found!
```

```
=
Error: Operand must be either a number or a single letter!
```

```
6abc<23
Error: Unexpected character found!
```

```
6<23
True
```

```
a=98
False
```

```
a=97
True
```